# number to words crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to show bill amount of 99.50 in words in Crystal Report.

How to do this? If bill amount is 99, it shows 'Ninety nine'. But it does not show decimal part as 'Fifty' :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new formula to your Report and set the syntax to *Basic Syntax*

This formula should do what you want.

```
Dim NumberAmount As Number

Dim LeftOfDecimal As String
Dim RightOfDecimal As String

NumberAmount = 99.50

LeftOfDecimal = ToWords(NumberAmount)
LeftOfDecimal = Left(LeftOfDecimal, InStrRev(LeftOfDecimal, " and")-1)

RightOfDecimal = ToWords(ToNumber(Mid(ToText(NumberAmount), InStr(ToText(NumberAmount), ".")+1,2)))
RightOfDecimal = Left(RightOfDecimal, InStrRev(RightOfDecimal, " and")-1)

formula = LeftOfDecimal + " and " + RightOfDecimal
```

I have used a variable called `NumberAmount` but you can easily change this to use your own Field Value from your datasource.